# Looking for Non Hosted Audio & Video Podcasting Solution for Church Websites

Tags: video, audio, podcast

I am looking for a solution that will do the following:

User uploads audio and/or video files with title, desc. image etc
Solution embeds info into ID3 tags
Solution generates RSS feed
Solution embeds new content in our website
Content on website is searchable

This is for a couple of church websites I manage.  I am looking for the ability to do the above with a sermon mp3 and also a video.  At the moment we are doing it with multiple steps / people involved and I want to automate the process.  I can't seem to find a solution that does all of the above.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[WordPress](http://www.wordpress.org) with [PowerPress](http://www.blubrry.com/powerpress/) does this all very easily.

Comment: My site is not on wordpress.

Comment: What is it running then? You still may be able to use it as the back-end for the podcasts.

Comment: It's not on anything.  It's a custom website.

Comment: That would have helped to begin with. However, I would still look into it. You could use WordPress/PowerPress as a back-end and hide the front-end with your custom site.

Comment: @motboys you can easily implement WordPress on all or part of your site and can make it so users cannot even tell it is WordPress. PowerPress makes all of it very easy. And as a bonus, 2.0 is in beta testing soon to be released

Answer (score 0):

Some people have gone to [Wizard Media](http://wizzard.tv/) you may want to check that out as well.